# How to allow user to continuously input elements into JList

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, jlist

I want to be able to allow the user to continuously add elements to JList. The program allows the user to input an element into the textfield and when the user presses the JButton, it will add it into the list. I was able to do so but my program would only allow me to override the previous element instead of adding a new element.

```
private JList list;
private JTextField textField;

private JButton followUser() {
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Follow User");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            DefaultListModel DLM = new DefaultListModel();
            String input = textField.getText();
            DLM.addElement(input);
            list.setModel(DLM);
        }
    });
    return btnNewButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in next: you always recreate `DefaultListModel` in `actionPerformed`, but you need to use model from your `JList` and adding elements to it. Try next example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    public TestFrame() {
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        final JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
        JButton add = new JButton("add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = field.getText();
                model.addElement(text);
            }
        });

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(field);
        p.add(add);

        JList<String> l = new JList<>(model = new DefaultListModel<>());

        add(new JScrollPane(l));
        add(p,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }




    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```